# Style ListBoxItem to use complete width of parent element

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a `ListBox` presenting items (`class Example`), which is style with a `DataTemplate` like that:

View

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Examples}" />
</Grid>
```

Skin

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Example}">
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Right" CornerRadius="7" Width="30" Height="30" Background="#96C0CE" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I get is this:

[image]

What I want is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to make one of the elements (probably the name) fill the panel by setting `LastChildFill` to `true` and moving it down.

Comment: @H.B. According to msdn LastChildFill = True is the default setting. Setting HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" does stretch the ContentPresenter, but the desired Icon is not alligned at right, but rather center. To align it to right LastChildFill = False should be set. At least it worked for me.

Comment: I dont know why, but you have to set HorizontalAlignment="Left" for the textblock and HorizontalAlignment="Right" on the border.....

Comment: @3615: Well, i moved the name block down and it worked; presumably because the border took most of the space before. Personally i would not even use a `DockPanel`, ever.